# Reuse html template in Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angular-template

I have this html template file, `range-details-dialog.tpl.html`

```
<div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
    <h5>Update Range</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form name="form" role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate ng-submit="updateRange()">
        <div class="form-group-attached">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group p-l-10 p-r-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.$invalid }">
                        <p ng-show="form.rangeDaily.$error.min" class="help-block">Daily range more than £5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 m-t-10 sm-m-t-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-t-5" 
             ng-disabled="form.$invalid || promise" promise-btn="promise" ng-click="updateRange()">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I want to have another file `forced-range-details-dialog.tpl.html`
These two files could be one file instead with dynamically populated placeholders.
These are the places were substitution would be needed:

1. `<h5>Update Range</h5>` would become `<h5>Update Forced Range</h5>`
2. `<p ng-show="form.rangeDaily.$error.min" class="help-block">Daily range more than £5</p>`

   would become:

   `<p ng-show="form.forcedRangeDaily.$error.min" class="help-block">Forced Daily range more than £5</p>`
3. `ng-disabled="form.$invalid || promise" promise-btn="promise" ng-click="updateRange()">Update</button>`

   , `ng-disabled="form.$invalid || promise" promise-btn="promise" ng-click="updateForcedRange()">Update</button>`

Is there a way to avoid having two separate template files for the above? Could you please provide some examples, links, or pointers as to how that can be achieved?

Also, I see in the answers that a solution would be to add a boolean parameter inside the component and then call it twice. I am not sure how to call the component though. I have pasted my component below:

```
 angular.module('app.investment.rangeDetails')
  .component('pxForcedLimitAmount', {
      templateUrl: '/assets/js/apps/range/range-details-dialog.tpl.html',
      bindings: {
          amount: '<',
          isRequest: '<?',
          requestedAt: '<?',
          @Input() isForced: boolean  //<<----I added this based on answers below
      },
      controller: [function () {
          var ctrl = this;

          ctrl.$onInit = function () {
              ctrl.isRequest = ctrl.isRequest === true || false;
          };
      }],
  });
```

Comment: Use a variable to toggle between divs and use `*ngIf` on the template.

Comment: @Natasha Kurian, can you please post an example or share a link to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like only the placeholders need to change, so you can use a variable to decide what placeholder to display on the template. For example:

```
isForced: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
   this.isForced = true; // decide how you want to toggle this
}
```

on the template:

```
<h5 *ngIf="!isForced">Update Range</h5>
<h5 *ngIf="isForced">Update Forced Range</h5>
```

and

```
<p *ngIf="!isForced" ng-show="form.rangeDaily.$error.min" class="help-block">
     Daily range more than £5</p>


<p *ngIf="isForced" ng-show="form.forcedRangeDaily.$error.min" class="help-block">
     Forced Daily range more than £5</p>
```

you can do the same for other tags as well.

---

From the comments, one way to "determine" the value for `isForced` is to introduce an input property to the component i.e.

```
@Input() isForced: boolean;
```

and invoke the component from elsewhere like:

```
<app-user [isForced]="true"></app-user>
```

Comment: Thank you! Where would the toggle functionality go though?  ngOnInit() {
   this.isForced = true; // decide how you want to toggle this
}

Comment: Edited the answer to illustrate by previous comment in detail/

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas K, I added property to the component (I updated the question and added the component) but I am not sure how to invoke it. Would I do it from a separate class, its sole purpose of would be to invoke the component twice? And could you please show me how an invocation of my component would look like?

Comment: No idea on angularjs. But me answer already includes how to invoke it from angular 2+ application. Also, please do not edit the question to add on new requirements - that should be another question IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputs.Write a component which takes input, and render it in html.  then call this component in desired places with its selector

For events use output

See the doc https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide a link to an example?

Comment: Documentations itself has examples. If you want to see more just type to google angular input you will see tons of thems